# Ubuntu 20.04LTS on Dell latitude 5520 - No RJ45 interface

Tags: networking, dell

I just reinstalled ubuntu 20.04LTS on a latitude 5520.
No problem during the installation, but surprise, the RJ45 ethernet card is not recognized at all even though a network cable is well connected.
I checked, it's not a problem with the cable or the internet connection, it's the card that is not recognized or active.
How to recover my RJ45 connection?
[image]
In advance, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Onboard Intel I219-V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344156/ubuntu-20-04-2-and-onboard-intel-i219-v)

Comment: The required driver *e1000e* has been in recent Ubuntu versions for several years. Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `modinfo e1000e | grep 15FB` as well as: `sudo modprobe e1000e` and, finally: `sudo dmesg | grep e100`

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348421/1133128), you will want to install the [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) kernel for the appropriate drivers to be included :

To do so:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```