# Intel Ethernet Adapter on laptop not working please help

Tags: 22.04, ethernet, intel, realtek

Situation: Dell 5420 laptop has an Intel Ethernet port. I setup dual boot. On the windows image, the Ethernet port and all networking works fine, so I know it's not a hardware problem. On the Xubuntu image the Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and usb-c internet work, but the ethernet port is not recognized. If I connect a cable, the port lights do light up as if it was working.

I reviewed dozens of similar questions on this website. I thought it must be the driver, so I tried downloading a driver from intel and doing make install but I don't really know what the problem is and I got weird errors. I have searched for a step by step troubleshooter but can't yet find one that applies to this situation.

Here's my setup:

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu\
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04\
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy\
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"\
```

```
# lspci | grep Eth
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)
```

```
# lsusb | grep Eth
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
```

```
# cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:  
  version: 2
  wifis: {}
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enx64c902a65521:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

```
# lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [8086:15fc] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [1028:0a20]
    Kernel modules: e1000e
71:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network:0               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s42f2
       version: 20
       serial: 64:79:f0:22:dc:8d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-56-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.u ip=192.168.1.208 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:605319c000-605319ffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 20
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a2300000-a231ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: f
       bus info: usb@6:1.3.3
       logical name: enx64c902a65521
       serial: 64:c9:01:b9:56:47
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-3 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.1.214 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

One commenter asked to see  /etc/network/interfaces. I don't have that file.  If I start typing the path and press tab here are the choices:

if-down.d/      if-post-down.d/ if-pre-up.d/    if-up.d/

A commenter asked to see systemctl status networking.service. This is the message I got:

> Unit networking.service could not be found.

The output of journalctl -xe. This command produced copious output:

```
A start job for unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished successfully.
 
 The job identifier is 39950.
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1725] device (wlp0s42f2): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1727] device (wlp0s42f2): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1729] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1734] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1735] policy: set 'anet2' (wlp0s42f2) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1739] device (wlp0s42f2): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc NetworkManager[2378]: <info>  [1680976553.1742] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc systemd-resolved[2322]: wlp0s42f2: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc systemd-resolved[2322]: wlp0s42f2: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.1.1
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc wpa_supplicant[2445]: wlp0s42f2: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-41 noise=9999 txrate=245000
Apr 08 12:55:53 mypc wpa_supplicant[2445]: wlp0s42f2: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-42 noise=9999 txrate=245000
Apr 08 12:55:54 mypc ntpd[2516]: Listen normally on 47 wlp0s42f2 192.168.1.245:123
Apr 08 12:55:54 mypc ntpd[2516]: bind(27) AF_INET6 fe80::5218:aa8c:8b8f:a493%3#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Apr 08 12:55:54 mypc ntpd[2516]: unable to create socket on wlp0s42f2 (48) for fe80::5218:aa8c:8b8f:a493%3#123
Apr 08 12:55:54 mypc ntpd[2516]: failed to init interface for address fe80::5218:aa8c:8b8f:a493%3
Apr 08 12:55:54 mypc ntpd[2516]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Apr 08 12:55:54 mypc systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
    Subject: Unit succeeded
    Defined-By: systemd
    Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

    The unit systemd-rfkill.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.

Apr 08 12:55:55 mypc systemd-networkd[2320]: wlp0s42f2: Gained IPv6LL
Apr 08 12:55:56 mypc ntpd[2516]: Listen normally on 49 wlp0s42f2 [fe80::5218:aa8c:8b8f:a493%3]:123
Apr 08 12:55:56 mypc ntpd[2516]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Apr 08 12:56:03 mypc systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
    Subject: Unit succeeded
    Defined-By: systemd
    Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

    The unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.

Apr 08 12:56:18 mypc rtkit-daemon[3680]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 08 12:56:18 mypc rtkit-daemon[3680]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Apr 08 12:59:50 mypc cups.cups-browsed[3713]: + true
Apr 08 12:59:50 mypc cups.cups-browsed[3713]: + sleep 3600
Apr 08 13:00:22 mypc rtkit-daemon[3680]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.

Apr 08 13:00:22 mypc rtkit-daemon[3680]: Supervising 3 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.

Apr 08 13:00:51 mypc sudo[180235]:   nathan : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/nathan ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
Apr 08 13:00:51 mypc sudo[180235]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
```

And ifconfig produces:

```
current: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.66.142.142  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.66.142.142
        inet6 fc00:bbbb:bbbb:bb01::3:8e8d  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 474261  bytes 555739928 (555.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 257554  bytes 36766584 (36.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 4 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx64c902a65521: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.244  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::66c9:1ff:feb9:5647  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 64:c9:01:b9:56:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 106951  bytes 96346373 (96.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 12  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60774  bytes 10918364 (10.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 7325  bytes 570341 (570.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7325  bytes 570341 (570.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s42f2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.245  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::5218:aa8c:8b8f:a493  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 64:79:f0:22:dc:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 280371  bytes 131084360 (131.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 16  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45099  bytes 23975647 (23.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm pretty sure that current is my VPN, enx64c902a65521 is a USB-C network connection from a docking station, and it works, wlp0s42f2 is my Wi-Fi adapter and that works too.

More info:

A commenter asked what I see in Netplan? Answer:There are two files in /etc/netplan/ 00-installer-config-wifi.yaml and  00-installer-config.yaml

Other commenters asked for this:

nathan@mypc:~$ sudo lsmod | grep 8153
r8153_ecm              16384  0
cdc_ether              24576  1 r8153_ecm
usbnet                 53248  2 r8153_ecm,cdc_ether
r8152                 114688  1 r8153_ecm
nathan@mypc:~$ sudo lsmod | grep e1000e
e1000e                299008  0

Another commenter asked what happens if booting from iso, so I tried that again on April 15, 2023. I only connected the ethernet. results:
Xubuntu 22 iso that I installed: network icon has red x, edit connections widget empty.
SystemRescue iso: same
Then I booted to windows to ensure the ETH card works again-yes.

Another commenter suggested booting from a different kernel, I booted from the oldest kernel available in Grub and that didn't fix the problem.

On 4/16 a commenter asked to see the output of dmesg | grep e1000e:

```
[    1.364567] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    1.364569] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.365087] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.586329] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[    1.700993] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -5
[   52.465417]  x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[34241.747685]  ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[34241.748348]  ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[61610.178033]  ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[61610.178743]  ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[85308.135585]  ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[85308.136291]  ramoops reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic zstd_compress dm_snapshot dm_bufio dm_crypt raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet r8152 mii raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid i915 i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul cec crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core i2c_i801 rtsx_pci_sdmmc aesni_intel nvme crypto_simd intel_ish_ipc psmouse cryptd intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss e1000e i2c_smbus rtsx_pci drm nvme_core thunderbolt xhci_pci intel_ishtp idma64 intel_pmt xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
```

Comment: 1. What does /etc/network/interfaces show? 2. What does systemctl status networking.service show? Also try journalctl -xe. 3. What does ifconfig show?

Comment: I’m not very well versed on this subject, but it appears that the driver for the Intel card isn’t loaded. Perhaps these links will help: [Intel Ethernet Connection I219-V not working under Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294753/intel-ethernet-connection-i219-v-not-working-under-linux-on-an-asuspro-b-laptop) [Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Onboard Intel I219-V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344156/ubuntu-20-04-2-and-onboard-intel-i219-v) [network UNCLAIMED (Intel I219-V) --ubuntu 16.04.2LTS](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2356217)

Comment: Regarding the reference to `/etc/network/interfaces,`' since it appears that you're running 22.04, Ubuntu defaults to using Netplan for configuration so you shouldn't see anything (as you correctly observed). Instead, can you please confirm what you see in `/etc/netplan` (hint: by default, it should be one  `yml` file)?

Also, I see a lot of chatter in your output referring to IPv6. To help reduce variables that might contribute to the issue, you may want to disable IPv6 (and re-enable if needed after you've resolved the issue).

Comment: Whoops... wanted to add that you might also want to run `sudo lsmod | grep 8153` to see what kernel module(s) are running for your device.

Comment: @richbl The vendor associated with RTL8153 is Realtek, which is his USB network card and is working fine. Perhaps `sudo lsmod | grep e1000e` instead? This is for the unclaimed Intel network card that isn’t working and is listed as the Kernel module for this card in `lspci -nnk`. I think the problem is that the driver isn’t automatically loading at boot for some reason and `modprobe e1000e` would probably fix the problem.

Comment: @mpboden, I think you're correct. I had read the device causing issues to be the RTL8153, but it appears that the kernel module may be e1000e as you note (for the controller, and not the adapter).

Comment: Can you show the output of this command? `dmesg | grep e1000e`

Comment: Added, noted NVM checksum msg, I wonder what that means?

Answer (score 3):

I have a Dell Latitude 5420 which uses the `e1000e` driver, and I have never had any issues.

It's curious that your `lshw` output doesn't shows the device as `UNCLAIMED` and no `driver=e1000e` but then your `lspci` output shows the driver is loaded.

Netplan configuration is irrelevant if the device remains unclaimed by any driver. Focus on that first.

Usually the answer would be just `modprobe e1000e` but it looks like something else funny is going on. You can maybe try `rmmod e1000e; insmod /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko`

Device name should be something like `enp0s31f6` by default - make sure you update your netplan config with this.

`journalctl -b | grep -iE nic\|e1000e\|net\eth` should show you some interesting info, as we as `/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg`

Comment: I tried 1) Connect eth port, lights come on. 2) Disconnect all other networks 3) sudo modprobe e1000e - cmd executes with 0 feedback. 3) Still no network so I reset the laptop. 4) Interesting while booting it paused for about 2 minutes on this msg: "Start job is running for wait for network to be configured" Never saw before. 5) After clearing, the eth port still didn't work so turned on wifi. Going on to your next suggestion now

Comment: btw after running modprobe e1000e and resetting, lswh -C still shows ethernet controller unclaimed

Comment: I just tried the rmmod/insmod, reset, saw same message at boot again. No change in status, eth port lights are blinkin, device still not working and shows unclaimed. I'm trying to find trustworthy complete instructions how to update netplan I don't know how.

Comment: I searched all over for simple trustworthy instructions to update netplan everything I found looks very complicated so I have not updated netplan. I found https://netplan.io/, https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration and lots of technical chatter. Basically for ~ 12 years I installed ubuntu on computers and networking devices just work- until this laptop.

Comment: The journalctl command you suggested brings up a lot of stuff about multiple devices, I scanned and don't see anything interesting. I have scanned the log and dmesg outputs and theres lots there but nothing I recognized as a clue to get the eth port working. Thanks for answering but the proposed solution didn't work.

Comment: Netplan configuration is irrelevant if the device remains unclaimed by any driver. Focus on that first.

Comment: Try booting from the ISO again and checking if it works - the issue could be something to do with installing the Intel drivers manually. Judging by your netplan config, you installed the system via the docking station?

Comment: I don't remember if it was connected to the thunderbolt docking station usb-C which provides power, network and dual extended monitors when I installed or not.

Comment: Maybe try a different kernel - you can find a list of available with `apt list linux-image*`

Comment: This answer did not fix the problem, ethernet still unclaimed. Following the recommendations in this answer made my laptop worse, now it takes longer to boot. Perhaps I need a new netplan config but this answer doesn't explain how to fix netplan.

Answer (score 1):

The correct module for your Intel card is `e1000e`. This is shown with the following command where it says `Kernel modules: e1000e`.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [8086:15fc] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [1028:0a20]
    Kernel modules: e1000e
71:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

Within this block, the first line of output describes your Ethernet controller, Intel I219-V. The **bus ID** is at the beginning: `00:1f.6`. At the end is the **Vendor ID** and **Device ID**: `[8086:15fc]`.

**Vendor ID**: `8086`

**Device ID**: `15fc`

With the following command, you can see that the `e1000e` module supports your Ethernet controller. I’m using the **Device ID** as a search pattern.

```
$ modinfo e1000e | grep 15FC
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015FCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

The full output of `modinfo e1000e` will show many aliases that indicate which devices the driver supports. This particular command shows just the alias for your Ethernet controller. Within this alias, you can pick out **Vendor ID** and **Device ID** which indicate that the driver supports your card.

```
v  00008086
d  000015FC
```

Now if you type in the following command, you should see the modalias for your device, and this will match the alias within the module shown in the output of `modinfo e1000e`. This device modalias is created dynamically during boot when the hardware is scanned. Notice that the directory structure uses the **bus ID** listed earlier. (I’m not displaying the output of this command, because I don’t have this device in my computer. But if you type it in, you should see your modalias for your Ethernet controller.)

```
$ cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/modalias
```

For more info about modalias, check out the following link:

[Modalias](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Modalias)

Anyway, your problem is not that you don’t have the correct driver or that it isn’t loading. It’s actually loading properly, and this command shows that it’s loaded:

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep e1000e
e1000e 299008 0
```

The problem is that it isn’t binding to your card because of the error: *NVM Checksum Is Not Valid*, which is shown in `dmesg`.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep e1000e

[    1.364567] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    1.364569] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.365087] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.586329] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[    1.700993] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -5
```

To fix, use the details at this link:

[Intel Ethernet Connection I219-V not working under Linux. e1000e driver reports: "The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid" li](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294753/intel-ethernet-connection-i219-v-not-working-under-linux-on-an-asuspro-b-laptop)

After that is fixed, run `ip a` and you should see that the card up.

`lshw -C network` will show that it’s no longer UNCLAIMED.

`lspci -nnk` should show that the driver is now bonded to your device with the line: `Kernel driver in use: e1000e`.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [8086:15fc] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V [1028:0a20]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Then finally add the network configuration to Netplan.