# Ethernet not working after power outage - network UNCLAIMED

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, ethernet

I have an Intel NUC i7 Series 11 used as a home server with Debian 5.10.70-1 installed. It has been running smoothly for about a year. Then came a power outage. When the power was back my server restarted as usual (these is a setting in the BIOS to configure it to restart after a power failure) but it would not connect to the internet via its cable ethernet port...

Due to my poor Linux knowledge my first investigations did not lead me that far and I decided to boot it on a USB stick with a freshly downloaded Ubuntu: this would remove the option of a corrupted OS or driver (?) and at least tell me whether it is a hardware or software issue.
Good news: the wireless connection is working
Bad news: still same problem with the ethernet connection

After a lot of searching here is a compilation of a bunch of commands (that I got from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446701/intel-ethernet-adapter-on-laptop-not-working-please-help) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/e1000e-probe-failed-with-error-2-a-4175688037/)) showing the state of my machine. Wireless is turned off and this is straight after a reboot:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:    23.04
Codename:   lunar

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:03:a8:ef:a0:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:0 DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: c4:03:a8:ef:a0:47
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-20-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6023114000-6023117fff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:96300000-9631ffff
```

Digging deeper on the `e1000e` driver:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V [8086:0d4f]
    DeviceName:  LAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V [8086:2081]
    Kernel modules: e1000e

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ modinfo e1000e | grep 0D4F
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D4Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep e1000e
e1000e                352256  0

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep e1000e
[    1.742428] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    1.742433] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.743423] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.130496] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): Failed to disable ULP
[    2.742996] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo rmmod e1000e

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe -v e1000e
insmod /lib/modules/6.2.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep e1000e
e1000e                352256  0

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep e1000e
[    1.742428] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    1.742433] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.743423] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    2.130496] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): Failed to disable ULP
[    2.742996] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
[  406.403047] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[  406.403049] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[  406.403269] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[  406.846574] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): Failed to disable ULP
[  407.406686] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -2
```

Notes:

1. The server went through many outages before with no issues. It has an UPS in front so it should be protected from electrical damage.
2. I am also seeing in some places (eg [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1792311/ubuntu-20-04-ethernet-unclaimed-cant-upgrade-kernel)) that the issue may come from missing or outdated kernel package, hardly applicable for me as I just downloaded it from the official Ubuntu website.
3. This [thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/e1000e-probe-failed-with-error-2-a-4175688037/) on a similar issue suggests that some BIOS may not comply completly to ACPI standards and therefore my cause unexpected behviors on power changes. I tried disabling ASPM in the BIOS to no avail (this was reverted before running the commands above)

Comment: Please see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625912/e1000e-error-with-b460-motherboard-and-intel-i219-v-chipset You have the same symptoms in the log. The answer was: "Turns out, it was most likely a hardware issue. I got a replacement motherboard" Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I get the exact same error when booting on Windows so I guess the issue and solution may be the same. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/nuc/boards/products.html You may be able to transfer your SSD and memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a hardware failure, my NUC was still under warranty and I got it replaced