# inet suddenly disappeared, after `dhclient`, it restarts, but won't last long

Tags: networking, netplan, inetd

I am new to ubuntu, but have to set up R/Rstudio server and work remotely.

Just moved the ubuntu server (Ubuntu 20.04) back home, and the connection became unstable while other PCs are working well.

Test connection with `ping 8.8.8.8`, shall stay connected for a short moment and soon turns unreachable.

when checking the `ifconfig`, the `inet` disappears as the pics.

[image]
[image]

after `sudo dhclient eth0`, the connection might come back for a while, but won't last long. Have tried `crontab` to re-initiate the ith0, but don't know why, it doesn't work.

also tried to modify the `netplan`, `interface`, but still not working.

Please advise.

---update
Here is the result for `sudo lshw -C network`
[image]

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`?  Please add the output to your question.  Thank you!

Comment: It is very possible when you have a `RTL8111/8168/8411` chipset and it has loaded the `r8169` driver that you get NIC failures like IP addresses disappearing.  I can only guess right now that this is what is going on.  If it is running the `r8169` driver I recommend that you install the `r8168` driver by running `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`

Comment: @Terrance thanks, pls find the updated information for your reference.

Comment: Unclaimed Intel I219-V means that the driver isn't loaded properly.  You will probably need the correct driver.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344156/ubuntu-20-04-2-and-onboard-intel-i219-v

Comment: @Terrance thanks for the advice